# Apache performance tuning for high traffic with MPM Event

Tags: performance, optimization, server, apache2, web-traffic

I currently manage the following set of servers that serve about 700 web pages:

### SERVER 1 (WEB)

- Web server: Apache 2.4.29 with MPM Event
- PHP 7.2.22
- CPU: Intel Xeon CPU E5-2673 v4 @2.30GHz (4 cores) 16GB memory
- S.O: Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

### SERVER 2 (DataBase)

- DB: mysql 10.2.26
- CPU: Intel Xeon CPU E5-2673 v4 @2.30GHz (8 cores) 32 GB memory
- S.O: Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS

Both servers are connected on the same local network.

Recurrently I have performance problems and I think it's because I don't have Apache optimized correctly.

The web server receives many web requests that it does not manage well and produces high CPU consumption and consequently slowness in the whole server.

Currently this is the MPM configuration I work with and I think it doesn't manage connections correctly:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers            2
        MinSpareThreads         25
        MaxSpareThreads         75
        ThreadLimit             64
        ThreadsPerChild         25
        MaxRequestWorkers       550
        ServerLimit             32
        MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone tell me an optimal configuration of the MPM according to the requirements and characteristics of the server?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me...." - No, because you've not said what the requirements are.  Even if you had the config depends on the nature of the traffic; running a Wordpress site is very different from a static content site. The following link describes how to optimize a prefork server, but the process is much the same for event: https://lampe2e.blogspot.com/2015/03/accurate-capacity-planning-with-apache.html

Answer (score 4):

Try these settings:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers            4
        MinSpareThreads         25
        MaxSpareThreads         75
        ThreadLimit             64
        ThreadsPerChild         25
        MaxRequestWorkers       800
        ServerLimit             32
        MaxConnectionsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

**The easiest way for configuring MaxRequestWorkers:**

*ServerLimit x ThreadsPerChild = MaxRequestWorkers*

Comment: Why do suggest using these settings?

Comment: ServerLimit * ThreadsPerChild = MaxRequestWorkers, Most of the time StatServers is set equal to number of cpu cores, btw if the you have a high load cpu usage or request, you need to check the keepalive timeout and request, or just run nginx as reserver proxy in front of apache might help.

Comment: But how are these settings going to reduce CPU usage? If anything, they will increase it by allowing more active connections. Its cheaper to keep clients in the backlog than in swap or forcing pre-emption of processes.

Comment: Well, My recommended settign was more about correcting his configuration, because as his configuration was like this: ServerLimit 32, ThreadsPerChild 25, but MaxRequestWorkers was 550, which was wrong and apache will ignore those settigns, the correct one is as I described in my comment. MaxRequestWorkers should be 800.

Comment: For reducing, should now the log first, apache status, and what's causing that issue, then might be able to fix that, I had same issue with big site high traffic, but I could fix it with some tweaking, so hard to know directly.